# What is debug? I want to know maybe my device has virus?

Tags: file-system

What is debug? I want to know maybe my device has virus? And mayby you can tell me what is this in the second screenshot?

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Comment: `/d` is just a symlink to `/sys/kernel/debug`, nothing to worry about it. For more details about that, **[check this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt)**.

Answer (score 1):

What is shown in your screenshots are just normal system files/directories:

- `/sys/kernel/debug` provides information for developers to closer investigate "system stuff" (here: Kernel information)
- the files in your second screenshot are system configuration files (`*fstab*` stands for "file system tab", a "table" with information of file systems existing on the device, and `init*` files are used during system startup, to initialize the components).

For some background, you can check our [file-system tag-wiki](/tags/file-system/info) and the questions linked at its end, plus corresponding Wikipedia articles.

As for viruses: There are no viruses for Linux or Android. If something bad happens, one has to find other reasons. But while malware indeed exists, it usually can only become active with active help from the user's end.